# how to create an transparent customized progress bar popup screen in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde

I have to create a progress bar screen to show the progress of download or during server interactions. I want it to be transparent and covers the screen fully. In center the popup progress should come  with the status.

please help me on this. provide me if any sample code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These series of KB articles should be your starting point. The author has provided detail explanations with all source code. You should be able to modify code to suit your requirements.

[Sample "Please Wait" screen - Part-1](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Sample-quot-Please-Wait-quot-screen-part-1/ta-p/493808)

[Sample "Please Wait" screen - Part-2](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Sample-quot-Please-Wait-quot-screen-part-2/ta-p/510363)

[Sample "Please Wait" screen - Part-3](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Sample-quot-Please-Wait-quot-Screen-part-3/ta-p/516996)